# How to create a 'blurred area' in a Map with Css?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, openlayers

I'm creating a web application where i need a certain area of the the map to be blurred.
To make it more easy we can say that i need 100x100 PX blurred in the left top corner.
The blurred area needs to be there even if i navigate to new places in the map.

And have a blur effect on only that box.
I'm working with SCSS, Javascript & Openlayer as a map provider.

I can blur the whole map with the following Css code bellow , but not only a specific area:

```js
this._map = new Map({
      target: "theMap"
    //openlayers code..



<div className="mapStyling" id="theMap">
<div classname="blurredBox"/>
</div>
```

```
.mapStyling{    
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;

//Code to create a blur
    -webkit-filter: blur(10px) saturate(10%);
    -moz-filter: blur(10px) saturate(10%);
    -o-filter: blur(10px) saturate(10%);
    -ms-filter: blur(10px) saturate(10%);
    filter: blur(10px) saturate(10%);

.blurredBox{
width: 100px;
height 100px;
margin-top:0px;
margin-left:0px;

//Here i want to 'Filter blur effect'
}
}
```

To problem here is that i don't get a blur effect if i move to "blur css code" down to blurredBox.

Would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Do you want to blur the whole map except the top right corner or the other way around?

Comment: Hi their,
I only want to have the top right corner blurred, the rest of the map should have no blur.

Answer (score 1):

Quite a bunch of error in your code. Lets me list them out:

- You declare a class in html by `class='xxx'`
- You are nesting `.blurredBox` inside `.mapStyling`, which it shouldn't be.
- Your css for `.blurredBox` `height` is wrong in syntax and miss a `:`. Your `with` is also wrong in vocab.

After fixing all of that, you should be able to have something like this [codepen](https://codepen.io/mankinchi/pen/Yopmpa)

I would recommend you open the developer tools on whatever browser you are coding on and check the css styling. Your idea is good and on point, just a bit more debugging. You can check on how to use css developer tool [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/css/)

Comment: Hi thanks for you answer!
1. I'm using react and i get "contact" with the css when i use classname="xxx"
2. Are you referring to the css code? I'm using SCSS so its posible to do nesting there.
3. The with misspell was a made when posting this, updated the post.

Any more ideas?

Comment: 1. Can you add react as a tag or update to say you are using react? 2. Can you put up some code to show that it's not working? Mine codepen is showing that it's working fine

Comment: 1. Yes sorry, Updated the tag with React instead of Javascript.
2. I don't see anymore code that could help to fix this problem. Yes that would work for me to if i just had a static img or background-color.
The problem is that i have a Map instead of a background-color: red; ( Referring to your Codepen link)

It's a Map and not a static background , that why it's gets tricky i'm afraid.